# Enum user-defined data-type in C programming

Tags: c, enums

I am studying about `enum` i.e keyword in `C` used to define a list of enumerators also known as enumeration constants to which the compiler assigns a signed integer value.

```
Syntax:
enum identifier (optional) { enumerator-list }
```

I was playing around `enum` to understand how the compiler assigned integers to enumeration constants in enumerated-list.

So when I wrote 3 different programs using `enum` as follows, I had some questions arose which are attached to every program below.

**Program-1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

enum days_of_week {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};

int main(void) {
    printf("%u %u %u %u %u %u %u\n", Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday);
    return 0;
}
```

`Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6` because when there are no integers assigned explicitly to the enumerated constants, then the compiler automatically indexes those enumerated constants on the basis of `zero-based indexing`.

**Program-2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

enum days_of_week {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday = UINT16_MAX, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};

int main(void) {
    printf("%u %u %u %u %u %u %u\n", Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday);
    return 0;
}
```

`Output: 0 1 65535 65536 65537 65538 65539`, as I have assigned a `UINT16_MAX` to `Tuesday`, before that, compiler assigned integers to enumerated constants on the basis of `zero-based indexing` and after `Tuesday` it assigned integers to enumerated constants on the basis of integer assigned to its previous enumerated constant + 1.

**Program-3**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

enum days_of_week {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday = UINT32_MAX, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};

int main(void) {
    printf("%u %u %u %u %u %u %u\n", Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday);
    return 0;
}
```

There was an error that the compiler `gcc 7.4.0` throws that was,

```
enum_example_1.c:8:58: error: overflow in enumeration values
enum days_of_week {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday = UINT32_MAX, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};
```

- From this, I concluded that the maximum integer which I can assign to these enumerated constants was `UINT16_MAX` but I have a question, is this value compiler/system dependent?
- At what step the compiler assigns these integer values to these enumerators, I mean do compiler assigns these values at compile-time or run-time?

The advantages of using `enum` over macros are:

- It increases the readability of the source code.
- Scope rule applies to the `enum` but not to macros.
- It does automatic initialisation of a signed integer to an enumerator constants/tags in the enumerator list.

**Apart from the listed advantages above, what are the other advantages of using `enum`, furthermore what are the use-cases where using `enums` is preferred over macros?**

Comment: The error was not assigning `UINT32_MAX` to `Tuesday`, but assigning `UINT32_MAX + 1` to `Wednesday`.

Comment: "whether a compiler assigns these values at compile-time or run-time" - the compiler itself is only present at compile-time, so it makes the decision of what values to assign at compile-time.

Comment: @pmg So, the maximum integer value which can be assigned to an enumerator is a `UINT32_MAX`. Thanks :)

Comment: In your specific compiler, with your specific flags, yes. The Standard ([see C11 p6.7.2.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2)) only requires "the type of constants is compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type"

Comment: There's a good explanation/discussion on `enum` in `C` on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum).

Comment: @striker No, the maximum value is `INT32_MAX` on your implementation, since enums are *signed* integral values. You should use `%d` (not `%u`) to print the values assigned to enum constants.

Comment: @Jens Thanks I thought that the enumerated constants can only take +ve int values.

Comment: I feel the word "string" a bit misleading. There is no (run-time) data type like a string assigned to an `enum` value. Actually it is a symbol for the compiler like a variable name, and its name will be unknown at run-time, you can't `printf("%s\n", Sunday);`

Comment: @thebusybee Yeah I know, edited the problem description, Thanks. So when we declare `enum {enumerated-list};` how does the compiler process this instruction?

Comment: Without exactly knowing I suppose that it stores each defined symbol (the names of the individual enum values) and assigns them their associated values. Whenever such a symbol is visible in the current context that expression is replaced by its value. I left out details like syntax checks, name spaces and debugging stuff, but you should be able to find a lot of it in compiler building documentations.

Comment: If you really want to get down and dirty with C obtain download and read the latest "final draft" of the C standard: currently C18. Earlier standards also had a "rationale" describing why the committees made some of the decisions and these can be a really huge aid in understanding C.  One such is available at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

Answer (score -1):

I modified **Program 1** to highlight a more specific programmatic technique that shows how to make an `enum` work with a `local array`, as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

enum days_of_week {Sunday = 3488, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};

const char *getDayOfWeek(unsigned int day);
const char *getDayOfWeek(unsigned int day) {
    static const char *days[7] = {
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday"
    };
    day -= 3488;
    day %= 7;
    return days[day];
}

int main(void);
int main() {
    static unsigned int day = (unsigned int) Thursday;

    printf("%X %X %X %X %X %X %X\n", Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday);

    if (day >= Sunday && day <= Saturday) {
        printf("The day of week is: %s (or %X).\n", getDayOfWeek(day), day);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See link at: https://ideone.com/IY39lR

Comment: 1. What does this answer in the question? -- 2. How do you make sure that enum names and string contents match? -- 3. Why don't you subtract `Sunday` instead of a magic number that is defined elsewhere?

Comment: Because these are the `hexadecimal characters` that are the printable portion of the word 'DAY' or 'DA' plus the array index of '0' to '6' for 'DA0' ... 'DA6' (see, 3488 = DA0 = "Sunday", 3489 = DA1 = "Monday", 3490 = DA2 = "Tuesday", 3491 = DA3 = "Wednesday", et cetera). *You only need to specify the first number in this particular sequence*

Comment: Don't write decimal numbers when you mean hex. And you didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: I'm a little cerebral, so I apologize about that. I could redo the code to show what the point is if you want...